# Need to create a way to assign values into an array using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my array ,

```
var alphas:string[]; 
alphas = ['abc1','abc2','abc3']  --> (this array will be change)
```

my modal class is ,

```
export class Team {
  TeamName: string;
}
```

And , I have to assign above alphs value into TeamName.
I do it like way ,

```
      let selectedTeams = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < alphas.length ; i++){
        let team: Team = new Team();
        team.TeamName = alphas[i];
        selectedTeams.push(team);
      }
```

then I need to call this method like way,

this.selectedReferredTo = [ selectedTeams[1] ,selectedTeams[2] , selectedTeams[3] ];

In here I'm stuck? can you help me to call above method in different array sizes?

Comment: Presumably you want `selectedReferredTo` not to refer to the team names at the time of the assignment, but references to the team names that can dynamically update as the source `alphas` array changes. Would it be sufficient to just store the indexes, or store an object with both the reference to the array and the index to check? Is there a reason to abstract it far enough away that `selectedReferredTo` stores zero-arg functions that return the names you care about?

Comment: The array is 0-based (the first one is selectedTeam[0]). Really I don't know the question. Yo can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `this.selectedTeams=this.alphas.amp(x=>{ conts team=new Team();team.TeamName=x;return team})`

Comment: @Eliseo this is helpful to resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

at the final step your code will look like

```
this.selectedReferredTo = [ ...selectedTeams ];
```